Unity c# help | Blocking switching between applications on iPhone
In my game project I made on unity, I need to draw lines on the screen continuously. So I need to use the whole screen on the phone. However, when I make a swipe gesture from left to right or from right to left in the safe area at the bottom of the screen on iPhones, when I make these swipe gestures in the safe area, it switches to other applications or puts the game in the background. On Unity, I checked all the places in the Defer system gestures on edges section for postponement but it did not help. When I enter the game, the home button should be active, I only want the background gestures to be canceled when I scroll in the bottom safe area. It should become passive. The priority should be the movements in the game. How can I solve this via unity? Or which code do I need to add?
I tried this code but it didn't work;

using UnityEngine;



public class SafeAreaAdjuster : MonoBehaviour

{

void Start()

{

ApplySafeArea();

}



void ApplySafeArea()

{

Rect safeArea = Screen.safeArea;



safeArea.yMin = 0;

safeArea.yMax = Screen.height;



Screen.safeArea = safeArea;

}

}

